# asp.net -> javascript -> webservice -> Returning two classes from webservice call

Tags: javascript, asp.net, web-services

Ok, I have a webservice that I created.  Initially, I created a class, populated that class, and then returned that class to my javascript.

psuedocode

```
Return myClass.toarray
```

....Turns out I need to pass even more data back during this call.  In turn I will have two classes that I need to pass back to my javascript.  I tried putting them into an array and that wasn't working I also tried some other things that didn't really make a lot of sense.  Any advice on this would be greatly appreciated, I am sure others have run into this type of situation previously. I know that you have to put them into an object but haven't figured out how to do this as of yet.

Basically, my question is, how do you pass two class objects back to javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think something along these lines may solve your problem

But even in this example the second class is like an inner class but you can get it easily on deserialization

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rakkimk/archive/2009/01/30/asp-net-json-serialization-and-deserialization.aspx

Comment: I ended up doing a wrapper class.  Kind of like what is shown here. :    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7105772/asmx-asp-net-webservice-return-multiple-classes-wsdl                                             But since this is such a great article and solution, I am marking it as answer.  Thanks for sharing such a good article.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this before. I decided not to return to class. Instead, I just try to combine both of my class into a single class. And then return the merged array. But this will depend on how you will use that array. If you want to separate them back. You may want to put special character as marker between the two stacks.

Comment: Yes, I thought about creating one single class, but I don't really like that idea.  I am striving for a way to somehow combine these two class objects and then return that combined object that contains two class objects.  (or something along those lines)